# npm run npm bin from within the same package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-run

I'm working on extending open source [`raml2html`](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html) library, which consumes raml contract to generate html docs. Key facts:

- the library has a **binary** placed in `bin/raml2html` file; th ebinary is stated in [`package.json`](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html/blob/9d4c33ab2dabfde39796a9a2c5cb23ce3fdd2a54/package.json#L42-L44) as follows:

  `"bin": {
      "raml2html": "./bin/raml2html"
    }`

  when `npm install`'ed by the users, the program is executed
- I use the binary to update [examples](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html/tree/9d4c33ab2dabfde39796a9a2c5cb23ce3fdd2a54/examples): both source .raml files and output .html files are kept in the repo. I'm using the binary with `./bin/raml2html examples/example.raml -o examples/example.html` with *git bash* under windows and it works fine.
- however, I want to wrap this commands as npm run script, so I define:

  `"scripts": {
      ...
      "examples:example": "./bin/raml2html examples/example.raml -o examples/example.html",
      "examples:github": "./bin/raml2html examples/github.raml -o examples/github.html",
      "examples": "npm run examples:example && examples:github"
    },`

  and when I call either `npm run examples` or `npm run examples:example`, both fail the same way:

`

```
$ npm run examples:example

> raml2html@2.4.0 examples:example C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Development\GitHub\raml2html
> ./bin/raml2html examples/example.raml -o examples/example.html

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "examples:example"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! raml2html@2.4.0 examples:example: `./bin/raml2html examples/example.raml -o examples/example.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the raml2html@2.4.0 examples:example script './bin/raml2html examples/example.raml -o examples/example.html'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the raml2html package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./bin/raml2html examples/example.raml -o examples/example.html
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs raml2html
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls raml2html
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tomasz.ducin\Development\GitHub\raml2html\npm-debug.log
```

It says that `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command` - well, that's true, `./bin/raml2html` is not how I should do that on windows. But it's being ran under node.js/npm layer and package.json:bin can understand this syntax. I get confused with that.

**The question is: how can I set up npm run scrpt to use the binary inside the same package?**

Comment: what about writing a bash script that you will call with `npm run` ?